# Which methods to be called if a screen share leave a OpenVido Session on Android?

Tags: android, webrtc, screensharing, openvidu

I have a problem related to Android and OpenVido. I connect from a computer and an Android tablet to a OpenVido Server. I would like to share my screen from the computer to the tablet. The first time everything works without problems and I can see the screen on the tablet. If I stop the screen share and start the screen share again, then it does not work anymore. After some research I figure out that the handler for unpublish a stream is not implemented on Android. The corresponding event which is sent from the OpenVido Server to the Android client is "JsonConstants.PARTICIPANT_PARTICIPANT_UNPUBLISHED".

Can anyone give me a hint which event or methods need to be triggered?

```
    private void handleServerEvent(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
        if (!json.has(JsonConstants.METHOD)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Server event lacks a field '" + JsonConstants.METHOD + "'; JSON: "
                    + json.toString());
            return;
        }
        final String method = json.getString(JsonConstants.METHOD);

        if (!json.has(JsonConstants.PARAMS)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Server event '" + method + "' lacks a field '" + JsonConstants.PARAMS
                    + "'; JSON: " + json.toString());
            return;
        }
        final JSONObject params = new JSONObject(json.getString(JsonConstants.PARAMS));

        switch (method) {
            case JsonConstants.ICE_CANDIDATE:
                iceCandidateEvent(params);
                break;
            case JsonConstants.PARTICIPANT_JOINED:
                participantJoinedEvent(params);
                break;
            case JsonConstants.PARTICIPANT_PUBLISHED:
                participantPublishedEvent(params);
                break;
            case JsonConstants.PARTICIPANT_LEFT:
                participantLeftEvent(params);
                break;
            case JsonConstants.PARTICIPANT_UNPUBLISHED:
                //Missing
                break;

            default:
                throw new JSONException("Unknown server event '" + method + "'");
        }
    }
```

Source of the code: https://github.com/OpenVidu/openvidu-tutorials/blob/master/openvidu-android/app/src/main/java/io/openvidu/openvidu_android/websocket/CustomWebSocket.java

Comment: `openvidu != openvino`, I believe you've used a wrong hashtag for this question

Comment: Yes. You are right.